# How to add full text feature to already installed SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-express

I have an installed version of SQL Server Express 2008 but it does not have the full-text service. Short of uninstalling and re-installing the Advanced Services version, what is the easiest way to add the full-text feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 steps involved

**Step 1 - Upgrade to Express with Advanced Features**
Run the installer for SQL Express 2008 Advanced Features on your existing Express install.  At the SQL Server Installation Center screen select `Maintenance`, then choose `Edition Upgrade`.  Run through this, it will let you upgrade your Express install to Express with Advanced Features.

**Step 2 - Add the Full Text Search Feature**
After you have completed the edition upgrade, rerun the Express with Advanced Features installer.  On the same screen as above, click `Installation` and then choose `New SQL Server standalone installation or add features to an existing installation`.  Run through that and it will let you add Full Text Search to your newly upgraded installation.

**Note:** In Step 2, on the Installation Type screen make sure you choose `Add Features to an existing installation of SQL Server 2008` instead of `Perform a New Installation of SQL Server 2008`.

Comment: Step 1 went OK, but for Step 2 I clicked on "New installation or add features to an existing installation" (the closest choice to the one you specified). I then get a dialog box asking me to browse "for SQL Server 2006 Installation Media". I do not know what to do next.